# Need to understand how to import module in python from one directory up

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a structure like this

```
pkg1
   __init__.py  
   file_1.py
   file2.py
pkg2
   test_1.py
   __init__.py
```

I have a structure like above. I have a code in `test_1.py` which is trying to load `file_1.py`

```
#test_1.py

from pkg1 import file_1
# from .. import file_1
```

Both statements are not working. How can I import the file_1 from pfg1

Comment: Make pkg2 a package with `__init__.py` and if it's `pytest` invoke it as `python -m pytest`

Comment: I tried this but not working. I already have a __init__.py which I forgot to mention above

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing modules from parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder)

Comment: How do you run tests?

Comment: @NizamMohamed: python <filename>

Comment: `python -m pytest` or `python -m unittest`

Comment: I am not using unittest or pytest. why should I use pytest or unittest. It is not mandatory

Comment: `PYTHONPATH=<path-to-pkg1> python <filename>`

Comment: Any idea using import statement without using env variables. How can i use absolute imports here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Comment: To use absolute import, pkg1 has to be in Python's import path.

Comment: pkg1 and pkg2 are unrelated. You can only use absolute import here.

Answer (score 0):

A python program can modify its path by adding elements to sys.path directly.
import sys then you can add to the system-path at runtime:

```
    import sys
    sys.path.insert(0, 'path/to/your/py_file')
    
    import py_file
```

or you can do this:

```
    import sys
    import os
    
    base_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__) or '.'

    # Insert the package_dir_a directory at the front of the path.
    package_dir_a = os.path.join(base_dir, 'package_dir_a')
    sys.path.insert(0, package_dir_a)
    import py_file
```